# Twilio voice call works only once [microphone permission issue]

Tags: javascript, angular, twilio

I implemented Twilio voice call functionality that enables users to call support people from the browser but it works the first time only after allowed microphone permission but then next time getting below error and resetting microphone permission then voice call works.

`code: 31000, message: "Cannot establish connection. Client is disconnected"`

Below is code snippet on the client-side that written in angular with help of [twilio client docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript/device)

```
import twilio from 'twilio-client';

public device: any;

this.device = new twilio.Device('<token-fetched>', {
    codecPreferences: ['opus', 'pcmu'],
    fakeLocalDTMF: true,
    enableIceRestart: true 
})

let params = {
    To: '<to-number>',
    Id: '<id>',
    token: '<token-fetched>'
}

if (this.device) {
    this.device.connect(params);
}

this.device.on('error', (error) => {
    console.log("this is error",error);
})

this.device.on('disconnect',(connection) => {
    console.log("connection ended", connection);
})
```

Comment: Is it possible that your token has expired?

Comment: @philnash I don't think so because resetting microphone permission then call again works. When microphone permission already given then it doesn't able to connect the call.

Comment: Do you use Capability Tokens or Access Tokens? Also, this doesn’t appear to be all of the code. How is this getting called?

Comment: @philnash Yes I use Capability Tokens that written as `<token-fetched>` and I fetched first then this code.

Comment: Could you try using [Access Tokens](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens?code-sample=code-creating-an-access-token-voice-2&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=3.x) rather than Capability tokens and see if that makes any difference.

Comment: @philnash Same scene with access tokens.

Comment: @JavascriptHuppTechnologies were you able to solve this problem? I faced exactly the same

Comment: @korovaisdead No :(, Client ended up with using plain javascript example with PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue here, the problem is that I was calling `var connection = Twilio.Device.connect();` before the async setup work had been completed.

Write device.connect inside of device.ready function like

```
    Twilio.Device.ready(function(device) { 
        console.log('Ready');                                       
        var connection = Twilio.Device.connect();
        // Do rest of twilio work ...!
    }
```

This will fix your issue.